# get job list queue from printer memory

Tags: c#, memory, network-printers

I know that my network printer (big Konica Minolta) have own memory and storage there some info like printed jobs. It is possible to get from this memory this information? I try to use Win32_Printer or Win32_PrintJob but as I read it gets only jobs queue from Windows dialog box ...

Have You some idea how resolve my problem ?

Comment: All Konica-Minolta printers allow communication using KM OpenAPI. If you use wireshark to listen in on communication between KM's "PageScope Account Manager" and the printer, you will find that a list of all available commands is handed out by the printer right at the start. On this list, you will find a command sounding like `JobList` - and then just try to understand the error messages until you have reverse engineered the required parameters. KM told me that these commands are not documented because they are for internal use only... (this is why they call it OpenAPI, I guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need the API/SDK specific to the printer:

> http://best.kmbs.us/pages/levels.php

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tnx, I think that this I looking for ;)